# How use a mutation function in a action function in Vuex?

Tags: javascript, vuex, vuex-modules

I have this `Vuex`:

```js
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    userInfo: {
      nit_ID: { ID: '', Desc: '' },
      userName: { ID: '', Desc: '' },
      typeDocument: { ID: '', Desc: '' },
      document: '',
    },    
    globalPublicKey: 'ASDFGHJKL1234567890',
  },
  mutations: {    
    updateUserInfo(state, payload) {
      state.userInfo = payload;
    }, 
  },
  getters: {
    userInfo: (state) => { return state.userInfo; },
  },
  actions: {
    validateUserSession(context) {
      var valido = false;
      try {       
        let storageInfo = JSON.parse(
          sjcl.decrypt(context.state.globalPublicKey, localStorage.userInfo)
        );
        if (localStorage.userToken === storageInfo.token) {
          context.mutations.updateUserInfo(storageInfo);          
          valido = true;
        }
      } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
      }
      return valido;
    },
  },
})
```

But the problem is that I can't access to the `mutation` `updateUserInfo()`, I know that is easy to solved, only do the `updateUserInfo` process in my action, but the question is **How can I use a `mutation` into a `action`?**

Comment: It's `context.commit`, see https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html

Comment: Yeah, `context.commit('mutationName', params)` - **params** can be omitted if not needed

Comment: @muka.gergely yes, thanks, post the answer please :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VueJS you can call a **mutation** from an **action** by calling **context.commit**, like this:

`context.commit('mutationName', params)`

**params** can be omitted if not parameters are passed to the mutation.

More on this here: [vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html)

Actually you call a mutation from anywhere with a **commit** - but it's advised to use **actions** (so **dispatch an action**) that in turn **commit**s the data (actually mutates the state).